Import and assign/manipulate the content of a huge number of files efficiently
I have a folder containing eg. around 40K txt files with randomly assigned names.
I am trying to import the content of these files as List/Table and process them for further manipulation eg. calculating average, standard deviations etc. out of the content of these files.
The content of these files look like below: say one such file (of around 60K size) :
cat 1727437735-output.txt
Header1 
Header2 
Header3 
1.00000000000000e-03
100000000  4.44681963074548e+09  2.26204260161459e+16

3.00000000000000e-03
100000000  3.66035848361298e+09  3.95912562444826e+15

...

Currently I am using FileNames to identify names of such 40K files and afterwards I am importing these files using Import and assigning the content to a function named  term[$i] using For loop.
Basically,
fileList; (**contains name(string) list of all 40K files**)
For[$i=1,$i<=Length[fileList],$i++,
 term[$i]=Import[fileList[[$i]],"Table"]; 
];

Once this is complete I could now manage all term[$i] to trim the headers and compute average, SD etc.
My question: importing a huge number of files (not huge-sized files) using For loop takes huge amount of time (~45mins), how can one improve this to speed up.
What I tried so far without any real improvement are the following:

Use of Parallelize enclosing the For loop does nothing.

Use of ParallelDo or ParallelTable does not even assign files to term[$i].

Without using For loop, I tried to simply assign as
term[$i_ ]:=Import[fileList[[$i]],"Table"]; 
but the computation/manipulation afterwards with term[$i] takes a huge time as before.


Some older thread suggests to simplify the input files lists (40K) and reduce them to a lower number which although is possible (by some other means), I am curious what are alternative approaches one can take to handle such a huge number of files in Mathematica.

Are you computing the statistics on rows or columns? And what do you do with the dangling rows (e.g. 1.00000000000000e-03)? Also, why are you taking the first part in Import[fileList[[$i]], "Table"][[1]]? If you're importing as Table, I would think that would lose data.

The statistic is on the every second row and second and third column i.e. one can think this as a plot with xvalue=1.00000000000000e-03, 3.00000000000000e-03 etc. with values 4.44681963074548e+09, 3.66035848361298e+09 etc. and error 2.26204260161459e+16,3.95912562444826e+15 etc. But this is only for a single file. I have 40K such files and they have similar structure. Final average is obtained from all such 40K files. One can ignore [[1]] as this is just a sample code(removed now).

Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?

If processing 14+ files a second is unbearably slow then a handful of lines of simple c code to accept a stream of file names, open each file, echo everything between the first and second newline and close the file should be faster than that.
